# The selectbox value is not updated if I use track by in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

When I use `track by` in `ng-options`, Angular doesn't update the selectbox value even if I choose one of the values in the selectbox. After second try, it works as expected even though the model value is already set.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        ['ali', 'ali']
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        value: {{selected}} <br><br>
        <select 
            ng-options="item[0] as item[1] for item in items track by item[0]"
            ng-model="selected"></select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Objective of track by is to use it with object not array elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually explained in the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions - look for the paragraph "select as and track by")

It seems that you cannot use `track by` together with some `select as` expressions.

But it works if for example you use `ng-options="item as item[1] for item in items track by item[0]"` instead of `ng-options="item[0] as item[1] for item in items track by item[0]"`

See https://jsfiddle.net/b9upojmb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Objective of track by is to use it with object not array elements. I would recommend you to use object. Here's an example

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { id :1, value : 'ali'},
        { id :2, value : 'ahmed'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        value: {{selected}} <br><br>
        <select 
            ng-options="item as item.value for item in items track by item.id"
            ng-model="selected"></select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented `track by` needs an array of `objects` then you can track by any object properties

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.items = [
                    { name : "ali" },
                    { name : "ben" },
                    { name : "bill" }
               ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        value: {{selected}} <br><br>
        <select 
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.name"
            ng-model="selected"></select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```